# Converting from C++ ifstream to C# FileStream

Tags: c#, c++, filestream, ifstream

I am attempting to learn SharpDX via DirectX tutorials. I have this line of code in the C++ project I am working from:

```
std::ifstream fin("Models/skull.txt");

if(!fin)
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Models/skull.txt not found.", 0, 0);
    return;
}

UINT vcount = 0;
UINT tcount = 0;
std::string ignore;

fin >> ignore >> vcount;
fin >> ignore >> tcount;
fin >> ignore >> ignore >> ignore >> ignore;

float nx, ny, nz;
XMFLOAT4 black(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

std::vector<Vertex> vertices(vcount);
for(UINT i = 0; i < vcount; ++i)
{
    fin >> vertices[i].Pos.x >> vertices[i].Pos.y >> vertices[i].Pos.z;

    vertices[i].Color = black;

    // Normal not used in this demo.
    fin >> nx >> ny >> nz;
}

fin >> ignore;
fin >> ignore;
fin >> ignore;

mSkullIndexCount = 3*tcount;
std::vector<UINT> indices(mSkullIndexCount);
for(UINT i = 0; i < tcount; ++i)
{
    fin >> indices[i*3+0] >> indices[i*3+1] >> indices[i*3+2];
}

fin.close();
```

And I would like to know how to covert this over to C#.  I am 99% sure I need to be using `System.IO.FileStream` but I am unsure how all the C++ stuff works.  What is really messing me up is the `fin >> ignore >> vcount;` If someone can explain to me how to do the same thing in C# I can probably figure it out from there.

As requested the text file resembles this:

```
VertexCount: 31076
TriangleCount: 60339
VertexList (pos, normal)
{
0.592978 1.92413 -2.62486 0.572276 0.816877 0.0721907
0.571224 1.94331 -2.66948 0.572276 0.816877 0.0721907
0.609047 1.90942 -2.58578 0.572276 0.816877 0.0721907
…
}
TriangleList
{
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
…
}
```

Comment: This may help. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: If you put your file contents here, then maybe we could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ignore` is declared as a `std::string`.  It appears that the original author of the code you are looking at was not aware of the `std::istream::ignore` function and is using a local variable to read in elements of the file they are simply discarding (that is, he didn't care about).  So the lines like:

```
fin >> ignore >> vcount;
```

Are reading in a string element (basically up to the first whitespace) and dumping it into the local string he is ignoring, and then reading in the `vcount` value (which he is storing as an `unsigned int`).

If you are going to port this to C#, you could do the same thing (read in parts of the file and simply discard them) and it would be a fairly direct port.

As an example (not tested):

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("File.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    // with your sample, this will read "VertexCount: 31076"
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    string sVCount = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(": ") + 2);
    uint vcount = int.Parse(sVCount);
    // ... read of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks - are you familiar with C# and `FileStream`?  If so could you update your answer with a small blurb of sample code to point me in the correct direction?  I no next to nothing about the System.IO stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot write the port for you as it is both off topic for SO, and I do not have the needed information to make an attempt (e.g. the input file and the list of desired values from it).  However, Microsoft has a **ton** of information on all of the CLR objects.  The one you would be most interested in for this task is:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look at it. I am not looking for a total port of the code; just how to do the equivalent of `fin >> ignore >> vcount;` in C#.

Comment: As it is reading in a string (to throw away) and then an integer, it would be a matter of reading in a line and finding the integer you cared about (and passing that portion of the remaining string to `int.TryParse` or `int.Parse` methods).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zac Howland's answer I was able to get everything working. For anyone else trying to convert Frank Luna's book from DirectX to SharpDX I hope this helps.  Here is what I ended up doing:

```
private void _buildGeometryBuffers()
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Chapter6/Content/skull.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open);

    int vcount = 0;
    int tcount = 0;
    //string ignore = string.Empty; // this is not needed for my C# version

    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs))
    {
        // Get the vertice count
        string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        string extractedLine = currentLine.Substring(currentLine.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
        vcount = int.Parse(extractedLine);

        // Get the indice count
        currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        extractedLine = currentLine.Substring(currentLine.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
        tcount = int.Parse(extractedLine);

        // Create vertex buffer
        // Skip over the first 2 lines (these are not the lines we are looking for)
        currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        currentLine = reader.ReadLine();

        string[] positions = new string[6];
        List<VertexPosCol> vertices = new List<VertexPosCol>(vcount);
        for (int i = 0; i < vcount; ++i)
        {
            currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
            extractedLine = currentLine.Substring(currentLine.IndexOf("\t") + 1);
            positions = extractedLine.Split(' ');
            // We only use the first 3, the last 3 are normals which are not used.
            vertices.Add(new VertexPosCol(
                new Vector3(float.Parse(positions[0]), float.Parse(positions[1]), float.Parse(positions[2])),
                Color.Black)
            );
        }

        BufferDescription vbd = new BufferDescription();
        vbd.Usage = ResourceUsage.Immutable;
        vbd.SizeInBytes = Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPosCol>() * vcount;
        vbd.BindFlags = BindFlags.VertexBuffer;
        vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
        _vBuffer = Buffer.Create(d3dDevice, vertices.ToArray(), vbd);

        // Create the index buffer
        // Skip over the next 3 lines (these are not the lines we are looking for)
        currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        currentLine = reader.ReadLine();

        string[] indexes = new string[6];
        _meshIndexCount = 3 * tcount;
        List<int> indices = new List<int>(_meshIndexCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < tcount; ++i)
        {
            currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
            extractedLine = currentLine.Substring(currentLine.IndexOf("\t") + 1);
            indexes = extractedLine.Split(' ');
            indices.Add(int.Parse(indexes[0]));
            indices.Add(int.Parse(indexes[1]));
            indices.Add(int.Parse(indexes[2]));
        }

        BufferDescription ibd = new BufferDescription();
        ibd.Usage = ResourceUsage.Immutable;
        ibd.SizeInBytes = Utilities.SizeOf<int>() * _meshIndexCount;
        ibd.BindFlags = BindFlags.IndexBuffer;
        _iBuffer = Buffer.Create(d3dDevice, indices.ToArray(), ibd);
    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

As always is someone sees a problem with the code or a better way of doing something I am always open to ideas.